# What is the order of the ink cartridges for a Canon i860?

Tags: printer, inkjet-printer, cartridge

I came across a Canon i860 for $10. It came with a box of ink cartridges, but none in it. So you can see my problem: what is the correct order of these cartridges?

Comment: Did you try a google search? It pointed me straight to the support website. Also, trying an image search yielded numerous results with images of the insides and cartridges. For example: http://www.justanswer.com/printers/4ynfk-canon-i960-blinks-yellow-times-one.html with the image https://www.usa.canon.com/app/images/service_ware/LDImages/SolutionAnswer/i960/i960_ink_order.jpg down on the page.

Comment: I did not know that, but looking at the pictures I linked, you're right. It's even in the printer itself :D

Comment: Please fix up your question. The title and the body are referring to different printer models.

Comment: I had tried - just hadn't tried correctly. As for in the printer itself: I'm handicapped and the aide who was looking for me swore up and down that there no such markings. When I showed her the attached graphics said "OOooooo that's what you meant!"

Answer (score 3):

According to the manual and some support websites, the i860 takes cartridges in the order:

`BK6 - BK3e - Y - M - C`

[image]

Comment: That picture and both links you provided are for the i960. The i860 OP referred to has only 5 cartridge slots; Edit: just noticed OP referred to the i960 in title and i860 in body. Sorry.

Comment: The title says i960...

Comment: Yeah, I was looking at the body and you were looking at the title. So no clue which OP is really referring to.

Comment: Also, same goes for i860, google is your friend here (http://www.steves-digicams.com/2003_reviews/canon_i860_pg2.html). Order is `BK - BK(large) - Y - M - C`